# Opera and Chromium via Snap using wrong screen resolution - how to fix? Kubuntu 20.04

Tags: display-resolution, snap

My primary display is 1440p (2560x1440). When I use Opera or Chromium through Snap, my screen resolution in-browser when fullscreen reports as 2047x1152 using Lagom.nl.
Both browsers also report 614x1092 on my secondary monitor, which is actually 768x1366.
There are also visible artifacts with videos and images at 'true' resolution, I assume because they are being upscaled from the reported resolution to fit the actual monitors.

Both monitors are set to the correct resolution in the display settings. Firefox as included with the OS reports correct resolution on both monitors, and no unusual artifacts are visible.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Versions if it matters:

- Kubuntu 20.04, up to date
- Snap 2.48.2
- Opera 73.0.3856.344
- Chromium 88.0.4324.96